# C++ recursive function why this code return 6

Tags: c++, recursion

I am studying for an exam in C++

I would like to know WHY THIS FUNCTION RETURN 6.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int s(int n);

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = 3;

   cout << s(a);

    return 0;
}


int s(int n)
{
   if(n == 0) {
     return 1;
   }

   return s(n-1)*n;
}
```

The first passage n value is 3 and must be return 6.
The second passage n value is 2 and must be return 4.

Why the final result is 6.
Maybe cout print only the first value ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code with a debugger to see *exactly* what it is actually doing?

Comment: This is a recursive function, you may use debugger to see what happen. It's expanding to 3*2*1 =6.

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to add in a few extra diagnostic print statements along the way to help you see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

`main()` prints the return value of `s(3)`.

`s(3)` returns `s(2)*3`

`s(2)` returns `s(1)*2`

`s(1)` returns `s(0)*1`

`s(0)` returns `1`

Thus, the result of `s(3)` is `(((1*1)*2)*3) = 6`

Answer (score 0):

This is how recursion works.

I suggest you follow the code in your head, or on a piece of paper.

First, `s()` is called with `3`. Since `n` is not `0`, the function returns `s(n-1)*n`. `n` at this point is `3`. To calculate `s(n-1)` that same function is called again (recursively), now with `n-1`, which is `2`.

And so on...